# Can I proxy HTTP requests to localhost on an external website?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, http, localhost

I'm developing an app, let's call it app A, which is embedded within another app, app B.

App A is embedded in app B as an iframe, and I regularly visit them both in my web browser for development. Let's say that app A is accessible via `https://app-a.com` and app B `https://app-b.com`.

Let's also say I'm running a server serving app A on my dev machine and thus it's accessible via `localhost:3000`.

I'd rather not start up app B on my dev machine, due to sluggish hardware, instead I would like all requests to `https://app-a.com` to proxy to `http://localhost:3000` inside my web browser (which happens to be Chrome), such that I can visit `https://app-b.com`, it would make some HTTP requests to `https://app-a.com`, which on my dev machine would reach not `https://app-a.com` but `localhost:3000`.

Is this possible? I'm running macOS 10.14.5.